# complex numbers and locus

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

When the problem says that the complex number $z$ moves on the straight line $y=2x$,what "clue" do I get from that? And generally when it says that a complex number belongs/moves to a conic section which thing should I considerate? My full problem is the following:

We have : $w=z+1/z$

$z$ moves on : $y=2x$

Find the locus (I am not sure if this is the correct word-I am foreigner) of $w$  /where $w$ moves.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That a complex number $z$ moves along a line means that

$$z=z_1 t + z_2$$

where $t$ is real, $z_2$ is on the line, and $z_1$ (or rather the line from the origin to $z_1$) is parallel to the line.

In your case lets pick a point on the line $y=2x$. It could be $z_2=(0,0)$. Since the line passes through the origin, we can take $z_1$ to be any other point on the line, sat $z_1=(1,2)$.

We can compute that

$$z=t(1,2)+(0,0)=(t,2t).$$

Let us put this in the equation for $w$.

We compute

$$\begin{align}w &=z+1/z\\&=(t,2t)+1/(t,2t)\\&=(t,2t)+\left(\frac{t}{t^2+4t^2},\frac{-2t}{t^2+4t^2}\right)\\&=(t,2t)+\left(\frac{1}{5t},-\frac{2}{5t}\right)\\&=\left(t+\frac{1}{5t},2t-\frac{2}{5t}\right)\end{align}$$

What happens now, if we square the real and imaginary parts of this number and we (conveniently) subtract?

Let $R:=t+\frac{1}{5t}$ and $I:=2\left(t-\frac{1}{5t}\right)$, be the real and imaginary parts of $w$. Let us compute $4R^2-I^2$.

We get

$$4R^2-I^2=16/5, \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ I think}.$$

Do you recognize this equation?

$$4x^2-y^2=16/5$$

Comment: Nuhh,i am supposed to come up with this: (x^2)/(4/5)-(y^2)/(16/5)=1.I am currently processing the above,(i expected it simpler..)

Comment: Ok that makes sense,but how you went from: 1/(t,2t) to (t/(t^2-4t^2),-2t/(t^2-4t^2))?

Comment: @Steven The [formula for the reciprocal of a complex number.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reciprocal.html) Or if you want, multiplying and dividing by the conjugate.

Comment: @Steven And you are right about the 5, I put a minus where it shouldn't be one and continued using it all along.

Comment: Got it.Still curious about the result..Is this supposed to be hyperbola? Edit:ok its all clear thanks

Comment: @Steven Yes,the equation that we got means that the points lay on a hyperbola. This doesn't quite prove that they cover the whole hyperbola. For this we must, in addition, check what values $t+1/5t$ takes when $t$ moves along all non-zero real numbers.